# Error with FixedJoint in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get the following error every time I run the code:

error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Joint.breakForce'

```
Joint.breakForce = Mathf.Infinity;
```

How can I properly write this? The break force can be set to Mathf.Infinity to render the joint unbreakable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see the error:

> An object reference is required to access non-static member [...]

This would strongly suggest that you are using a class name where you should actually be using a class instance. In this case, it's saying that you need an instance of `Joint` (or rather, `FixedJoint`, right?) in order to change its `breakForce` value.

To fix this, you will first need to use `GetComponent()` to retrieve the instance of `FixedJoint` from the current `GameObject`, and only then set its `breakForce`. For example, if you do this in your `Start()` method:

```
Start() {
    GetComponent<FixedJoint>().breakForce = Mathf.Infinity;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.